# How does ASP.NET CORE project in a VS2015 solution resolve other library references?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-pipelines-build-task

How does ASP.NET CORE project in a VS2015 solution (VS2015 with update 3) resolve references to other .Net Core library projects in the same solution (see project structure below)? Local developer running VS2015 does not have any issues but “Visual Studio Build” step on VSTS fails to reference the correct version of .Net Core Libraries.

(all projects are part of the same solution but different folders on the hard drive)

> MySolution.sln__contains__My .NET CORE Library Project#1"
>
> MySolution.sln__contains__My .NET CORE Library Project#2"
>
> MySolution.sln__contains___CORE project__Referencing Project#1 and Project#2"

This is how the other projects are referenced in the project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "LibraryProject1": "1.0.1-*",
    "LibraryProject2": "1.0.1-*",
    }
```

For now, to make it work I have to change the version number for each .Net core library to make sure the solution build step on VSTS picks up the right version.

Again, developers don't run into this issue.

Comment: As the tooling now moves to Visual Studio 2017 RC, can you upgrade and try again? The MSBuild based new project format should work better with existing tools like TFS/VSTS.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue even though there is global.json file in the solution root folder. What're build steps? Can you share a project on the OneDrive, which can reproduce that issue?

Comment: @starain-MSFT: These are the build steps I followed:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `global.json` file in the solution root folder. And its `projects` section is what you are looking for (from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json)):

> Specifies which folders the build system should search for projects when resolving dependencies. The build system will only search top-level child folders.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Its helpful and pointed me in the right direction. My folder structure is this: C:\Applib\webProject\global.json (solution file is in this folder too) ,  C:\Lib\Project1, C:\Lib\Project2. I tried adding relative paths in global.json file but still its not working. Is the only way to make it work is to move lib projects under the same folder as solution and global.json ?

Comment: @MuazzamAli AFAIK path to any folder could be specified and both relative and absolute path may be used. Keep in mind that the build system will only search top-level child folders. If your project.json files location are C:\Lib\Project1\project.json and C:\Lib\Project2\project.json, then this relative path should work: '..\..\Lib' (or relative path 'C:\Lib')

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried all combinations of relative paths and it still does not work. I will try moving it in same folder and see if that works. If not then I will skip the VS build and switch to DOTNET RESTORE pointing to nuget package folders for libraries.